# Reading phantoms rendered HTML into R

Tags: javascript, r, phantomjs, rvest

Problem: using rvest I can't seem to locate the block of information I need from an html page that I rendered through phantom js. I have tried almost every possible format but I can't seem to get html_node to pick up the right block.

html rendered from phantoms:

```
<div class="page">

<div class="main-header">    
</script>

    <div id="listing-703036966" class="shop-srp-listings__listing">
        <div class="card listing-row--search hide-fade">

            <div class="listing-row__main">
                <div class="listing-row__image">

                    <div class="media-count shadowed">
                        <a href="/vehicledetail/detail/703036966/overview/" target="_self" class="media-count--photo" data-goto-vdp="703036966" data-standard-link="md-thumb">
                            25 Photos
                        </a>

                            <a href="/vehicledetail/detail/703036966/overview/" target="_self" class="media-count--video" data-goto-vdp="703036966" data-standard-link="md-thumb">
                                1 Video
                            </a>
                    </div>

                    <a href="/vehicledetail/detail/703036966/overview/" target="_self" class="gray-bg listing-row__photo" data-goto-vdp="703036966" data-standard-link="md-thumb">
                        <img alt="New 2018 BMW 750 i" src="https://www.cstatic-images.com/phototab/e/1/4/e2/f87fb57ec51cab4f57cbaeb9f9f.jpg" onload="window.performance.mark('serverSideFirstPhotoLoaded')">
                    </a>
                    <div class="compare-srp">
                        <div class="listing-row__save">
                            <a id="703036966" class="switch-favorite unsaved saveVehicleHeart  compare-switch-favorite" savedfeatureinstance="" vehicle="{&quot;listingId&quot;:703036966,&quot;mkId&quot;:20005,&quot;mkNm&quot;:&quot;BMW&quot;,&quot;mdId&quot;:20536,&quot;mdNm&quot;:&quot;750&quot;,&quot;trimId&quot;:25905,&quot;trimName&quot;:&quot;i&quot;,&quot;modelYearId&quot;:35797618,&quot;modelYear&quot;:2018,&quot;stkTyp&quot;:&quot;New&quot;,&quot;state&quot;:&quot;NC&quot;,&quot;zipcode&quot;:&quot;27107&quot;}" cars-common-omniture-custom="" omniture-events="">
                                <div class="save-icon-wrapper">
                                    <div class="cui-icon icon-heart-line">
                                        <svg width="16" height="16" class="icon-image">
                                            <use xlink:href="#cui-icon-heart-outline"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="cui-icon icon-heart">
                                        <svg width="16" height="16" class="icon-image">
                                            <use xlink:href="#cui-icon-heart-fill"></use>
                                        </svg>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <p class="saved-label">Save</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="compare-button" data-compare-listing="703036966">
                            <div class="compare-icon-wrapper">
                                <div class="cui-icon icon-plus-sign">
                                    <svg width="16" height="16" class="icon-plus-sign">
                                        <use xlink:href="#cui-icon-plus-sign"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cui-icon icon-checkmark">
                                    <svg width="16" height="16" class="icon-checkmark">
                                        <use xlink:href="#cui-icon-checkmark"></use>
                                    </svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p class="compare-button__label compare">Compare</p>
                            <p class="compare-button__label added">Added</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

etc

What I have done in R

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)

cars <- read_html("my file.html") %>%
    html_nodes("div") %>%
    html_text()
```

However, when I inspect the cars vector I am completely missing the desired code block which is:

```
<a id="703036966" class="switch-favorite unsaved saveVehicleHeart         compare-switch-favorite" savedfeatureinstance="" vehicle=".   {&quot;listingId&quot;:703036966,&quot;mkId&quot;:20005,&quot;mkNm&quot;:&quot;BMW&quot;,&quot;mdId&quot;:20536,&quot;mdNm&quot;:&quot;750&quot;,&quot;trimId&quot;:25905,&quot;trimName&quot;:&quot;i&quot;,&quot;modelYearId&quot;:35797618,&quot;modelYear&quot;:2018,&quot;stkTyp&quot;:&quot;New&quot;,&quot;state&quot;:&quot;NC&quot;,&quot;zipcode&quot;:&quot;27107&quot;}" cars-common-omniture-custom="" omniture-events="">
```

But it never gets converted to a useable form and all of the different nodes I try lose it (div, p, span).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking to parse the bracketed content from a single node.
i.e: string *"vehicle='{"listingId":703036966,..."*, from node with css path *"a id.703036966 saveVehicleHeart"*.

As this node does not contain text to be rendered in an html browser, the command html_text() will get you nowhere. Instead, you can store as a string the node's code, and then parse the sections of interest.

**1. Retrieve the node's strings.** One of several possible css paths to the node is *'.saveVehicleHeart'*

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
car_html <- read_html("my file.html")
cars <- as.character(html_node(car_html, css = '.saveVehicleHeart'))
```

**2.Extract the content within brackets "{ }"**

```
cars <- cars %>%
str_match(., "\\{.*?\\}") %>% ## Extract everything between the first "{" and the subsequent "}" 
gsub("\\{|\\}", "", .) ## Remove the characters "{" and "}"
```

**3. Bonus. Get it into a nice data frame.** You did not ask for this, but it might be helpful.

```
df_cars <- cars %>% 
   cbind(read.table(text = ., sep = (','))) %>%
   t() %>% 
   as_data_frame() %>%
   .[-1,] %>% ## The first row contains the original unparsed string. We drop it.
   separate(., V1, into = c("Variable", "Value"), sep = "\\:")
df_cars

# A tibble: 12 × 2
      Variable     Value
*        <chr>     <chr>
1    listingId 703036966
2         mkId     20005
3         mkNm       BMW
4         mdId     20536
5         mdNm       750
6       trimId     25905
7     trimName         i
8  modelYearId  35797618
9    modelYear      2018
10      stkTyp       New
11       state        NC
12     zipcode     27107
```

Comment: By "full html" are you referring to what you posted or to an even larger html with multiple car posts?

Comment: I figured it out..html_node vs html_nodes. Thanks again! Response is perfect